# SUSY how to keep rows separate

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass

If with a SUSY grid I want

```
[column1 of copy] [column2 of copy]
[column3 of copy now on a new row] [column4 of copy]
```

...that is I want a new row for my column3 and column4 text regardless of how tall columns are, is there a pure SUSY way of achieving this?

I am finding that if the content of column2 is tall (a lot of text) then column3 'pops up' to sit directly under column1, so I assume a clear is not being applied—I am using the `omega` directive for the last item in each row and was naively assuming this was a magic bullet that also ensured row clearing.

I am solving this for now with

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

between each row but I wonder if I am not understanding part of SUSY and perhaps I can achieve this with pure SUSY statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extra markup, or help from Susy, there's a super-simple css way to handle this. That's exactly what the `clear` property is for. All you need is this:

```
.column-three { clear: both; }
```

You can clear `left`, `right`, or `both` to drop an item below floats on either or both sides.  Susy doesn't have any feature for it because I can't find any way to make it simpler or more meaningful than it already is.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks Eric—very happy just to know that I should just use 'normal' CSS in this circumstance and that I wasn't missing something about SUSY. Thank you & colleagues btw for SUSY.